# Como usar 'native' no Java?

Tags: java, característica-linguagem

No Java temos a palavra-chave `native`. Essa palavra-chave permite o Java delegar a sua execução para C e/ou C++ permitindo-o fazer certas coisas que ele não é capaz.

Considerando que eu conheço os conceitos de C e C++, como eu utilizo essa palavra-chave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, vamos entender o que é *native* em Java.

Simplificando, a sua definição está correta, este é um **modificador de acesso** usado para acessar métodos implementados em uma linguagem diferente de Java como C / C ++

Essa funcionalidade indica a implementação dependente da plataforma de um método ou código e também atua como uma interface entre a [JNI][1] e outras linguagens de programação.

A seguir, um exemplo ilustrativo:

- Crie um arquivo helloworld.java

```java
class HelloWorld
    {
    public native void printText ();
    static
   {
   System.loadLibrary ("helloworld");
   }
    public static void main (String[] args)
   {
   HelloWorld helloworld = new HelloWorld ();
   helloworld.printText ();
   }
    }
```

- Compile

  % javac helloworld.java

A funcionalidade **javah** do compilador Java gerará as declarações necessárias e outras da nossa classe HelloWorld. Isso criará um arquivo HelloWorld.h para incluir em no código C:

```
% javah HelloWorld
```

Para aliviar a necessidade de escrever códigos tediosos para que o código C possa ser chamado no sistema em tempo de execução Java, o compilador Java pode gerar automaticamente o código necessário:

```
% javah -stubs HelloWorld
```

Agora, basta escrever o código real para imprimir dar Oi ao mundo. Por convenção, devemos colocar o código em um arquivo com o nome da classe Java com a string "Imp" anexada a ele. Isso resulta em **HelloWorldImp.c**. Coloque o seguinte no HelloWorldImp.c:

```c
#include &ltStubPreamble.h>      
#include "HelloWorld.h"         
#include &ltstdio.h>         
void HelloWorld_printText (struct HHelloWorld *this)
    {
    puts ("Hello World!!!");
}
```

Em seguida, compile os arquivos de origem C que criados. Você deve informar ao compilador onde encontrar os arquivos de suporte ao método nativo Java:

```
% gcc -I/usr/local/java/include -I/usr/local/java/include/genunix -fPIC -c HelloWorld.c HelloWorldImp.c
```

Agora, crie uma biblioteca compartilhada a partir dos arquivos de objeto resultantes (.o) com o seguinte comando:

```
% gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libhelloworld.so.1 -o libhelloworld.so.1.0 HelloWorld.o HelloWorld.o
```

Copie o arquivo da biblioteca compartilhada para o nome abreviado padrão:

```
% cp libhelloworld.so.1.0 libhelloworld.so
```

Por fim, caso você use Linux:

```
% export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Agora é só executar:

```
% java HelloWorld
```

Para ir além:

https://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~bigonha/Cursos/Ap/Native/JavaNativeMethod.html
ftp://ftp.inf.puc-rio.br/pub/docs/techreports/02_03_carasso.pdf